# Pocket Door Hardware Issue

Tags: pocket-door

I cannot figure out how to assemble the pocket door mortise hardware I bought. I bought the same Santa Monica hardware for 3 pocket doors, and all of them came with front and back plates that both have what appear to be male connectors (see below):

[image]

Looking at other similar hardware online, there is a male side and a female side. Initially I thought I might need to pull one of them out and slide it into the other side, but that isn't possible. You cannot remove them, and while both posts are obviously too long, reducing this to only one seems like it would be an extremely tight fit on a 1.75" thick door, which is what it says is the minimum for a flush mount.

So then... should I just cut the metal off with a dremel or something? I don't know what kind of metal it is, but it seems very solid. Is it normal to need to cut those off? I can't find any videos online of anyone working with Baldwin Hardware specifically, nor even a mention of just cutting hardware like this. HELP!

Comment: The "instructions" at https://www.baldwinhardware.com/p/santa-monica-small-pocket-door-set-passage?variant=pass-pd006-056 do seem uselessly vague, so call them at the number listed there 800-566-1986 and ask directly. It would appear that using a cutoff disk in a dremel-type tool (very hard metal no problem) to make each shaft go halfway into the lock mechanism must be the way, but they don't show or mention that *at all.* ...or does the lock mechanism have square holes in different locations on the different sides, so you just flip one of the outside plates?

Comment: The small round hole fully in the picture to the right seems like the right location for a square hole on the other side, and one outside plate flipped top to bottom so the shafts don't have to share a hole...

Comment: Maybe there's supposed to be a male/female pair, but they accidentally shipped a homosexual pair.

Comment: Maybe you just remove the pin/shaft from one side, so that the other one will slot into the hole.

Answer (score 1):

From the install guide, via @ecnerwal’s link in comments:

[image: cut the spindles]

They say cut the spindles for any normal door.

Comment: THANK YOU! I completely missed that, and I have looked at those dozens of times!